# File is corrupt and cannot be opened, when exporting using OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I am using the below function to Export the data, by making the excel sheet in the memory stream, using the data retrieved from the Database. Whenever the file is exported, it says corrupt.

---

```
      private void ExportObjectToExcel(List<ExcelData> excelData, System.Web.HttpResponse Response)//string destination)
        {
            string[] columns = { "Barcode", "Client", "Content_Owner", "IsClientVisible", 
                   "Material_Type", "Client_Barcode", "MaterialId","Standard",
                   "Class", //"Subtitle_Language", "Subtitle_Type", 
                   "Title_Name",
                   "Language", "StartOfMessage", "EndOfMessage", "StartOfRecording",
                   "EndOfRecording", "Audio Channels"};
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            string filename = "ETMetaData.xlsx";
          //  using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook,true))
            {
                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();


                var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                var sheetData = new SheetData();
                sheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

                Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
                string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);
                AddStyle(workbookPart, relationshipId);
                uint sheetId = 1;
                if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                {
            sheetId =
                sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                }

                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "Element Profiles" };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                Row headerRow = new Row();

                foreach (var column in columns)
                {
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column);
            headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (ExcelData data in excelData)
                {
            int i = 0;
            Row newRow = new Row();
            CreateCellForValue(columns[0], data.Barcode, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[1], data.Client, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[2], data.Content_Owner, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[3], data.IsClientVisible.ToString(), newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[4], data.Material_Type, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[5], data.Client_Barcode, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[6], data.MaterialId, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[7], data.Standard, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[8], data.Class, newRow);
            //CreateCellForValue(columns[9], data.Subtitle_Language, newRow);
            //CreateCellForValue(columns[10], data.Subtitle_Type, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[9], data.Title_Name, newRow);
            CreateCellForValue(columns[10], data.Language, newRow);
            if (data.TimecodeItem != null)
            {
                CreateCellForValue(columns[11], data.TimecodeItem[i].StartOfMessage, newRow);
                CreateCellForValue(columns[12], data.TimecodeItem[i].EndOfMessage, newRow);
                CreateCellForValue(columns[13], data.TimecodeItem[i].StartOfRecording, newRow);
                CreateCellForValue(columns[14], data.TimecodeItem[i].EndOfRecording, newRow);
            }
            else
            {
                CreateCellForValue(columns[11], string.Empty, newRow);
                CreateCellForValue(columns[12], string.Empty, newRow);
                CreateCellForValue(columns[13], string.Empty, newRow);
                CreateCellForValue(columns[14], string.Empty, newRow);
            }
            CreateCellForValue(columns[15], ((data.AudioChannels != null) ? string.Join("|", data.AudioChannels.Select(x => x.ToString())) : ""), newRow);
            //CreateCellForValue(columns[18], data., newRow);
            //  i++;
            sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }            
            }
            memoryStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";

            //  NOTE: If you get an "HttpCacheability does not exist" error on the following line, make sure you have
            //  manually added System.Web to this project's References.

            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            byte[] data1 = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
            memoryStream.Read(data1, 0, data1.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
            Response.BinaryWrite(data1);
            Response.Flush();

            //  Feb2015: Needed to replace "Response.End();" with the following 3 lines, to make sure the Excel was fully written to the Response
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }

     private void CreateCellForValue(string column, string columnValue, Row newRow, bool isLock=false)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(columnValue);
                if (isLock)
                    cell.StyleIndex = 0;
                newRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

      private string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell)
            {
                if (cell == null || cell.CellValue == null)
                    return null;

                string value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
                if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                {
                    return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                }
                return value;
            }

 private void AddStyle(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string id)
        {
            CellFormat lockFormat = new CellFormat() { ApplyProtection = true, Protection = new Protection() { Locked = true } };
            WorkbookStylesPart sp = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<WorkbookStylesPart>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (sp == null)
                sp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
            sp.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
            sp.Stylesheet.CellFormats = new CellFormats();
            sp.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild<CellFormat>(lockFormat);
            sp.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)sp.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements.Count);
            sp.Stylesheet.Save();
        }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger and looked at what it's writing out at runtime?

Comment: Debugger doesnt help here much, no error while debugging. :(

Comment: There may not be an error, but you should be able to see what it's outputting and find the problematic line of code.

Comment: simplify that part at the end by writing `var data1 = memoryStream.ToArray()`, then save the resulting file and analyze it with a binary file viewer. it may be altogether empty, have a wrong encoding, contain semantic errors, that should be narrowed down before looking any further.

Comment: First of all, write to disk for debugging purposes and to know if the problem is in the `Response`. Secondly, the code sample lacks of the helper functions `AddStyle`, `CreateCellForValue`... Can´t help much ATM

Comment: I have now pasted the other functions as well.
During debug, I can only see the values for cellvalues, and they exist.

What exactly needs to be look for cause of file corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rahul,
I used your code and saved the Excel data to a local Excel file.  I have confirmed that the file is corrupt. When I open the file in Excel2016 it points to the `Styles` part as being corrupt - see image:

[image]

I commented out your `AddStyle` method and replaced it with another method created by the Open XML Productivity Tool and it worked.  See file here:

[image]

I have [saved this code to GitHub and you can inspect it there](https://github.com/thomasbtatum/GenerateAnyExcelFileWithCSharp/tree/FixCorruptOutput).  There is a wrapper WPF application that asks you for a filename and then saves the file.  There is some mocked `ExcelData` (2 rows) that generate some throw away data.

If you dont have Excel 2016, this tool can help show you errors in OpenXML files.  Just open any Open XML file and click the validate button.